# Asynchronous postbacks causing full postbacks

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, postback

I have an asp.net page within which I've used several AJAX controls doing partial postbacks with update panels. In testing it works wonderfully, all of the postbacks are done without reloading the page and it makes the whole process smooth. I uploaded this to the web server for some outside testing and all of the tested reported that the page was reloading a lot. I tried it within the network from the web server and it was still working fine. However, when I tried it from outside the network at home, it does in fact appear to be doing full postbacks whenever it's set to do partial postbacks for these update panels.

I can't seem to find out why this is happening. Even with the increased time it takes to communicate with the server, it shouldn't reload the page - it should just, at most, stall for a moment. Another strange thing is that it's not maintaining the scroll position even though I have it set to do so for the one or two full postbacks I have. It reloads to the top of the page.

I'm thinking perhaps this may be something set on the server, but I can't be sure. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the AJAX wasn't being loaded because the axd files were being filtered by the firewall of our network for having .  It was a tough find because there are a great deal of reasons why AJAX might not be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Check with firebug or similar so that all javascript files are loaded correctly. Both console errors and .js files downloading errors. Maybe possible you cannot access some files outside the network?

Comment: This was the beginning of it, but it was much more complex.